# Issues With Managed Package Upgrade

Tags: managed-package, upgrade

I released managed version of my package say 1.0 with some changes and now I have released another version say 1.1 with some changes in existing components which were present in V 1.0, but few of them aren't upgraded with new version

Here are the details:-

- I created a Lightning Application with name say "Lightning
  Application" in V 1.0 , now I edited the name with Label say
  "Lightning Only" (API Name begin same), I was considering it should
  be upgraded with label "Lightning Only" but it didn't.
- I created a custom object tab in V1.0 and later in V 1.1 I added custom logo for that tab, I thought new logo will be reflected on custom object tab when package is upgraded , but it didn't.(I have added logo in Document and that is available in package)

  However when I am installing V1.1 in fresh org (Not Upgrading the existing package) these changes are reflecting as they should be, aren't these two things mentioned above are up-gradable?

(I was checking [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) for reference.)

Comment: As subscriber can change these details as well. So I think SF does not allow them to overwrite again. Thats why your changes doesn't reflect in old org.

Comment: @TusharSharma yeah that was my thought as well , but if these are part of package then upgrading these changes might not affect subscriber just a thought.

Comment: if subscriber has changed the details then your upgrade will override his changes. Thats why SF don't push your changes or let subscriber decide.

Comment: @TusharSharma Agreed !! or if SF could add option to let subscriber deiced whether they want to override changes or not during package upgrade may help in such scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installation the subscriber org can update certain component attributes. For instance, with a tab they can edit the Tab Style. Subsequent package upgrades won't overwrite these attributes to avoid changing what the subscriber could have customized.

See [Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) in the ISFforce Guide for what is and isn't subscriber and developer editable.

---

Idea provided by Nachiket: [Option To Override Components and Attributes During Package Upgrade](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TsOTQA0)

Comment: I have created an Idea for this:- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TsOTQA0